# scrape through website with href references

Tags: python, recursion, web-crawler

I am using scrapy, and I want to scrape through www.rentler.com.  I have gone to the website and searched for the city that I am interested in, and here is the link of that search result:

```
https://www.rentler.com/search?Location=millcreek&MaxPrice=
```

Now, all of the listings that I am interested in are contained on that page, and I want to recursively step through them, one by one.

Each listing is listed under:

```
<body>/<div id="wrap">/<div class="container search-res">/<ul class="search-results"><li class="result">
```

each result has a `<a class="search-result-link" href="/listing/288910">`

I know that I need to create a rule for the crawlspider and have it look at that href and append it to the url. That way it could go to each page, and grab that data that I am interested in.

I think I need something like this:

```
rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow="not sure what to insert here, but this is where I think I need to href appending", callback='parse_item', follow=true),)
```

**UPDATE**
**Thank you for the input.  Here is what I now have, it seems to run but does not scrape:**

```
import re
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from KSL.items import KSLitem

class KSL(CrawlSpider):
    name = "ksl"
    allowed_domains = ["https://www.rentler.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.rentler.com/ksl/listing/index/?sid=17403849&nid=651&ad=452978"]
    regex_pattern = '<a href="listing/(.*?) class="search-result-link">'

    def parse_item(self, response):
        items = []
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = re.findall(regex_pattern, "https://www.rentler.com/search?location=millcreek&MaxPrice=")

        for site in sites:
            item = KSLitem()
            item['price'] = site.select('//div[@class="price"]/text()').extract()
            item['address'] = site.select('//div[@class="address"]/text()').extract()
            item['stats'] = site.select('//ul[@class="basic-stats"]/li/div[@class="count"]/text()').extract()
            item['description'] = site.select('//div[@class="description"]/div/p/text()').extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 7):

If you need to scrape data out a html files, which is the case, I would recommend using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), it's very easy to install and to use:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

bs = BeautifulSoup(html)
for link in bs.find_all('a'):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        print link.attrs['href']
```

This little script would get all `href` that are inside `a` HTML tag.

**Edit: Fully functional script:**

I tested this on my computer and the result was as expected, BeautifulSoup needs plain HTML and you can scrape what you need out of it, take a look at this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get(
    'https://www.rentler.com/search?Location=millcreek&MaxPrice=').text
bs = BeautifulSoup(html)
possible_links = bs.find_all('a')
for link in possible_links:
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        print link.attrs['href']
```

That only shows you how to scrape href out of the html page you are trying to scrape, of course you can use it inside scrapy, as I told you, BeautifulSoup only needs plain HTML, that is why I use `requests.get(url).text` and you can scrape out of that. So I guess scrapy can pass that plain HTML to BeautifulSoup.

**Edit 2**
Ok, look I don't think you need scrapy at all, so if the previous script gets you all the links that you want to take data from works, you only need to do something like this:

supposing I have a valid list of urls I want to get specific data from, say price, acres, address... You could have this with the previous script only instead of printing urls to screen you could append them to a list and append only the ones that start with `/listing/`. That way you have a valid list of urls.

```
for url in valid_urls:
    bs = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)
    price = bs.find('span', {'class': 'amount'}).text
    print price
```

You only need to look at the source code and you'll get the idea of how to scrape the data you need from every single url.

Comment: I do not have any experience with BeautifulSoup.  Does it run inside Scrapy?  I have added new code above, would you still suggest BeautifulSoup? Thanks. @PepperoniPizza

Comment: @benknighthorse Take a look at the new example, try it in your computer as it is and see the results.

Comment: This is great @PepperoniPizza.  I ran the script and it functioned as expected.  Now I need to add this into Scrapy and feed it these results.  I have NOT a clue how/where to begin.  Can you give me a pointer or place to start?

Comment: Are you scraping links only out of https://www.rentler.com/search?Location=millcreek&MaxPrice= ?

Comment: @benknighthorse You can use this script on any html and it will find the links out of it, I really don't know how to help you more, it's straight easy I think.

Comment: I am trying to scrap the price, bedrooms, baths, acres, cost, address, description of each of those links.  I am able to land on a page and get what I need with Scrapy.  The part I cannot figure out is how to go through each of those links.  I need to tell Scrapy the set of links and then have it go through each of them and grab the data that I need.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to find all the rental home ids from the links. From there, you can use the ids you have and scrape that page instead.

```
import re
regex_pattern = '<a href="/listing/(.*?)" class="search-result-link">'
rental_home_ids = re.findall(regex_pattern, SOURCE_OF_THE_RENTLER_PAGE)
for rental_id in rental_home_ids:
   #Process the data from the page here.
   print rental_id
```

**EDIT:**
Here's a working-on-its-own version of the code. It prints all the link ids. You can use it as-is.

```
import re
import urllib
url_to_scrape = "https://www.rentler.com/search?Location=millcreek&MaxPrice="
page_source = urllib.urlopen(url_to_scrape).read()
regex_pattern = '<a href="/listing/(.*?)" class="search-result-link">'
rental_home_ids = re.findall(regex_pattern, page_source)
for rental_id in rental_home_ids:
   #Process the data from the page here.
   print rental_id
```

Comment: Thank you for this advice.  I have added the code, and it runs without error, but is not scraping.  Could you take a look? @GKBRK

Comment: I think i found the error @benknighthorse. You put the link in re.findall(). Instead, you need to put the page source code. I don't know how its done with scrapy, but it's probably not hard.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @GKBRK.  What exactly is SOURCE_OF_THE_RENTLER_PAGE ?

Comment: @benknighthorse It is the page HTML source. You can see my edit for how to use it.